# SendGrid API Domain authentication response - authorization required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Recently we have decided to work on the domain authentication workflow through SendGrid API endpoints (https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/domain-authentication/authenticate-a-domain)

As per the documentation, I have setup the request for the domain authentication, but the response I got was 401 status code stating,

Request:

```
sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'], host: nil, request_headers: {'on-behalf-of' => 'None'})
data = JSON.parse('{
  "domain": "example.com"
}')
response = sg.client.whitelabel.domains.post(request_body: data)

puts response.status_code
puts response.body
```

Response:

```
401
{"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"authorization required"}]}
```

I have used the same SendGrid API key for other use cases, like getting the scopes of the API key (https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/api-key-permissions/retrieve-a-list-of-scopes-for-which-this-user-has-access) and sending the email through SendGrid, and also I have enabled **Full Access** for it.

But for other API endpoints like authenticating the domain and creating API keys, it throws the same error like 'authorization required'.

Can someone explain regarding this?